# Memory Effecient Object creation in Java

Tags: java, object, memory-management

I have a basic doubt regarding object creation in java.Suppose i have two classes as follows

```
Class B{  
    public int value=100;  
}

Class A{  
    public B getB(){  
        return new B();  
    }  
    public void accessValue(){
        //accessing the value without storing object B
        System.out.println("value is :"+getB().value);

        //accessing the value by storing object B in variable b       
        B b=getB();
        System.out.println("value is :"+b.value);

   }  
}
```

My question is,does storing the object and accessing the value make any difference in terms of memory or both are same?

Comment: Have a look at the generated byte code...

Comment: The code doesn't even compile, please elaborate.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka: It does if you put the classes in separate files. I think the OP combined his code for simplicity.

Comment: There is a little bit of information here about how local variables are stored if you are interested: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#15722

Comment: @Joonas:Ok well.There are two approach to access "value".1) get an object of B and store it in a variable b and then access the data member "value". 2)get an object of B using getB() and directly access "value".My question is whether both 1 and 2 are same in terms of memory efficiency.

Comment: @JoonasPulakka -- Other than the minor typo of using "Class" vs "class", the code compiles and executes just fine.

Comment: @EvanMulawski -- No need to put the classes in separate files.  I put them in a single file along with a public `main` class and it compiled just fine.  You can include *non-public* classes in the same file as a single *public* class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both equivalent, since you are instantiating `B` both times. The first way is just a shorter version of the second.

Answer (score 2):

Following piece of code is using an anonymous object. which can't be reused later in code.

```
//accessing the value without storing object B     
System.out.println("value is :"+getB().value);
```

Below code uses the object by assigning it to a reference.

```
//accessing the value by storing object B in variable b             
B b=getB();      
System.out.println("value is :"+b.value);
```

Memory and performance wise it's NOT much difference except that in later version stack frame has an extra pointer.

Comment: Minor addition: I believe the anonymous object also goes out of scope (and so becomes available for garbage collection) straight away.

Comment: Yes, agree! As no reference is attached to it. it must be sweeped in next GC run.

Comment: Though, as a practical matter, in a method this small the `b` will be out of scope only microseconds after the anonymous object.

Answer (score 1):

It is the same. This way: B b=getB(); just keeps your code more readable. Keep in mind, that object must be stored somewhere in memory anyway.

Comment: Actually, at the bytecode level, in the first version the value is held in the "stack", and never "stored".  But that's just a conceptual distinction, of course, as the stack location and "storage" location would only be separated by maybe 20 bytes in memory.  And, once JITCed, the value would be held in register in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you never reuse the B-object after this part, the first option with an anonymous object is probably neater:

the second option would need an additional store/load command (as Hot Licks mentioned) if it isn't optimized by the compiler

possibly first storing the object in a variable creates slight overhead for the garbage collector as opposed to an anonymous object, but that's more of a "look into that" than a definitive statement of me

If you do want to access a B a second time, storing one in its own variable is faster.

EDIT: ah, both points already mentioned above while I was typing.

Answer (score 0):

In that case the difference, if any, would not be worth mentioning.  In the second case an extra bytecode or two would probably be generated, if the compiler didn't optimize them away, but any decent JIT would almost certainly optimize the two cases to the identical machine code.

And, in any event, the cost of an extra store/load would be inconsequential for 99.9% of applications (and swamped in this case by the `new` operation).

**Details:** If you look at the bytecodes, in the first case the `getB` method is called and returns a value on the top of the stack.  Then a `getfield` references `value` and places that on the top of the stack.  Then a StringBuilder `append` is done to begin building the `println` parameter list.

In the second case there is an extra `astore` and `aload` (pointer store/load) after the `getB` invocation, and the setup for the StringBuilder is stuck between the two, so that side-effects occur in the order specified in the source.  If there were no side-effects to worry about the compiler might have chosen to do the very slightly more efficient `dupe` and `astore` sequence.  In any case, a decent JIT would recognize that `b` is never used again and optimize away the store.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no difference in the second instance you are just giving the new object reference to b.

So code wise you cannot achieve the println if you use version 1, as you dont have any reference as you have in the second case unless you keep creating new object for every method call.

Comment: The println will work as well in the first case as it would in the second.

Comment: how without creating a new object ?

Comment: It will, of course, create a new object, in the called method getB.  It's a separate call.

Comment: so does it make sense to keep on creating a new object just to call a method, thats what my answer is

Comment: No, but this is a toy example.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to say the difference without looking at the generated machine code. It *could* be that the JIT puts the local variable "b" onto the stack. More likely however that the JIT will optimize b away. Depends on the JRE and JIT you are using. In any case, the difference is minor and only significant in extremely special cases.

Comment: To preserve side-effect order the JITC can't "optimize away" b, but it can hold it in a register, making the logic essentially identical in both cases.